# Can i integrate Karate with any test management tools like Testrail?

Tags: ui-automation, karate, web-api-testing

I have a requirement to use any test management tools like Zephyr or Test rail to manage test cases and Need to integrate that with my automation framework. We have not decided on tools yet but i am thinking to go with Karate and try it out. But only thing i am worried is the integration part to the test management tools using Karate. i am not seeing any proper answer or demo to that question. Can someone help me and tell if i can achieve that with Karate?

Comment: if the linked q&a does not answer your question, you can choose to contribute code and findings - or look for another framework